# Magnetic monopole

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

I've been watching a lot of videos claiming to make monopoles either by dropping the temperature to 5k (-268° C) and splitting the magnet or by pouring molten metal through an induction system and was just wondering, how true these systems are?

Comment: They are certainly not true monopoles, because they have not been discovered. (Although there are many theoretical reasons to think that they might exist.)

Comment: The videos you watched are mistaken. What condensed matter physicists have discovered aren't *really* magnetic monopoles, but are instead just [quasiparticles that superficially resemble monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#.22Monopoles.22_in_condensed-matter_systems). The people who made the videos you watched probably just don't understand the difference.